# How can I store time based data in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a web application in Django. I have a system that will send a signal every minute to the application of how many people are in a building. I then want to be able to acess the data of a building (model) to e.g. display it in a graph (amount of people in the building during the course of an hour), or look up how many people there were e.g. at 5.30pm last wednesday.

How can I build this into a model where I can look up data based on date/time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really vague, so it's hard to give a detailed response, but you could always try something along the lines of this:

```
# models.py
class BuildingCount(models.Model):
    number_of_people = models.IntegerField()
    datetime_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then the signal creates the model:

```
b = BuildingCount(number_of_people=x)
b.save()
```

A datetime is a continuous field, so you're better off filtering between two datetimes then trying to get a record at a specific datetime. Here are a couple of examples:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# All counts in the past week
now = datetime.now()
one_week_ago = now - timedelta(days=7)
results = BuildingCount.objects.filter(datetime_stamp__range=(one_week_ago, now))
for result in results:
    print (result.number_of_people)

# Last Wed 5.30pm
# filter over a 2 min window and return the first record
result = BuildingCount.objects.filter(datetime_stamp__range=(datetime(2016,11,2,17,29), datetime(2016,11,2,17,31))).first()
print (result.number_of_people)
```

Hopefully this helps, alternatively if you provide more information I may be able to assist further...

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I wasn't too sure about my question's wording either. I wasn't sure if there was suitable built-in Django functionality or if I would need a plugin. I like your answer, it is certainly something I could do and build from. Do you think it would be okay for the scenario: each Building has lists of BuildingCounts (say every hour in a 12 hour day) for 50-100 Buildings running up to a year or longer? Giving 4,368 BuildingCounts per Building, with 50 Buildings that would be 218,400. I am unsure if this is a manable data size for Django?